# Reading Text In C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 500
int main(){
 int JourneyId;
    char Date[MAX];
    int Hour;
    char BusDriver[MAX];
    char Departure[MAX];
    char Destination[MAX];
    int BusCapacity;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen( "Journey.txt" , "rt");

    if(file){   
        while (fscanf(file,"%d,%s,%d,%20[^,],%20[^,],%20[^,],%d", &JourneyId,Date,&Hour,BusDriver,Departure,Destination, &BusCapacity) != EOF){
        printf("%d,",JourneyId);
        printf("%s",BusDriver);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Error");
    }
    return 1;   
}
```

I want to read text file and use this code for adding BST.But If I run , Output is infinite loop.How can I read text file ?
Text file which I want to read:

```
80,15.04.2014,10,Henry Ford,NewYork,Paris,45
40,15.04.2014,11,Nikola Tesla,Londra,NewYork,40
```

Comment: You should put a space, both before and after, each comma in the file so that %s won't read beyond a comma. And in the format string accordingly. That may fix your problem.

Comment: `fscanf(file,"%d,%11[^,],%d,%20[^,],%20[^,],%20[^,],%d",...`

Comment: I tried methods which you offeri But It gives same result(Infinite Loop)

Comment: Change to `while (fscanf(file,"%d,%s,%d....) == 7)`.  Likely some thing of your input is choking on the `fscanf()` and we need to find the offending line.

Comment: @chux I tried and result is nothing.It didn't write anything

Comment: What is your `fscanf()` return value?

Comment: @chux Return value is false so While loop doesnt work

Comment: @Semih The return value of `fscanf()` is an `int`:  the number of successful conversions (or `EOF`).  Sounds like you are receiving a `0`. Correct?  Minor: change `"rt"` to `"r"`.  BTW: if the `if()` is false, you should not get nothing, but get "Error". Are you getting "Error"?

Comment: The best way to get to the bottom is to use `fgets()` to read the line of text and `sscanf()` to parse it.  We can separate the IO issues from parsing that way.

Comment: Yes I am receiving a 0. I changed "rt" to "r".

Comment: There _must_ be something about your text file that does not begin with an `int`.  Good luck: GGTG

Comment: :) I think , I can try to use fgets() . Because my text file begins with an int .

Comment: Meanwhile , Thank you @chux.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than read a text file using `fscanf()`, *strongly* recommend using `fgets()` and then parsing via `sscanf(), strtok(), strtol()`, etc.  Check all function return values. It is much easier to cope with the unexpected - which is certainly what is happening in OP's case.

Using modified format from @BLUEPIXY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 500

int main() {
  int JourneyId;
  char Date[MAX];
  int Hour;
  char BusDriver[MAX];
  char Departure[MAX];
  char Destination[MAX];
  int BusCapacity;
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen("Journey.txt", "rt");

  if (file) {
    char buf[MAX*4 + 20*3 + 6*1 + 3];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
      int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%d,%499[^,],%d,%499[^,],%499[^,],%499[^,],%d",
              &JourneyId, Date, &Hour, BusDriver, Departure, Destination,
              &BusCapacity);
      if (cnt != 7) {
        printf("Unexpected input \"%s\"", buf);
        break;
      }
      printf("%d,", JourneyId);
      printf("%s\n", BusDriver);
    }
    fclose(file);  // Be sure to close
  } else {
    printf("Error opening\n");
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BLUPIXY indicated, The following functions (tried on SuSE Linux / gcc)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 500

int main(){
    int   JourneyId;
    char  Date[MAX];
    int   Hour;
    char  BusDriver[MAX];
    char  Departure[MAX];
    char  Destination[MAX];
    int   BusCapacity;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen( "Journey.txt" , "rt");
    if(file)
      {
//    while(fscanf(file,"%d,%s,%d,%20[^,],%20[^,],%20[^,],%d", &JourneyId,Date,&Hour,BusDriver,Departure,Destination, &BusCapacity) != EOF){
      while(fscanf(file,"%d,%11[^,],%d,%20[^,],%20[^,],%20[^,],%d", &JourneyId,Date,&Hour,BusDriver,Departure,Destination, &BusCapacity) != EOF){
      printf("%d,",JourneyId);
      printf("%s",BusDriver);
      }
   }
else
   {
   printf("Error");
   }

return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am using windows 8 64 bit and Dev-C++ 5.6.2. I tried this method and result is the same(Infinite loop)

Comment: Semih,  I am sorry for your troubles.  I am using gcc on Suse Linux 11.  It printed both fields of both records and terminated without incident.

Comment: No problem , Thank you for sharing your knowledge to me. :)